# How can one get Synergy to share in Fedora 15/Gnome3 with window maximized?

Tags: linux, synergy, fedora-15, gnome3

I have my synergy server running on Fedora 15, I'm starting it with "Synergy" in .bash_profile. There's another Fedora 15 client. Sharing normally works fine, given that a window is not maximized.

I've not had this issue with Synergy running on Fedora 14, Windows 7, or Windows XP.

Note: Sharing works fine with Firefox, whether it is maximized or not.

Answer (score 1):

As root

Edit your GDM Init file -  This runs at machine boot.

```
vi /etc/gdm/Init/Default
```

On the client machine add the following line near the end of the file before the line with exit.

```
/usr/bin/synergyc -n {ClientName} {ServerName}
```

Replace ClientName with the machine name being installed on.  Replace Server Name with the name (or IP) of the machine with the keyboard plugged in.

On the server machine:

Launch synergy, configure the screen geometry as desired.  Save the configuration file.  Move the configuration file to /etc/synergy.conf.   Make sure file is owned by root

```
chown 0:0 /etc/synergy.conf
```

Edit your GDM Init file -  This runs at machine boot.

```
vi /etc/gdm/Init/Default
```

add the following line near the end of the file before the line with exit.

```
/usr/bin/synergys
```

If you change clients or screen configuration,  repeat the save and file move for synergy.conf